# How to match entries between datasets?

Tags: openrefine

For Example, I have a dataset like this:

```
| People      | ID  |
|-------------|-----|
| John Smith  |A1234|
| John Doe    |A1235|
| Jane Doe    |A1236|
| John Smith  |A1237|
```

And I also have another dataset like this:

```
| People      | Company | City   | Rank  |
|-------------|---------|--------|-------|
| John Smith  | XXX     |New York| 1     |
| John Doe    | YYY     |London  | 2     |
| Jane Doe    | ZZZ     |Seoul   | 3     |
| John Smith  | WWW     |Tokyo   | 4     |
```

I want to find the company of each people in the first table, using the information in another table. Note there're people with the same name (though few) in the second (and also the first) tables, so we need other columns for assistance.

Is it necessary to import two tables in one project? The reality is I have multiple tables providing possible name / company matchings, but they have little similarity (i.e. different dataset provides entirely different information) other then each dataset have name and company rows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create two separate OpenRefine projects and join them using the [cell.cross](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Other-Functions#crosscell-c-string-projectname-string-columnname) function. You can also see this [tutorial for joining two projects in OpenRefine](http://kb.refinepro.com/2011/08/vlookup-in-google-refine.html)

`cell.cross` performs the equivalent of a database join. You will need a unique identifier common to your two projects for the function to match the records, otherwise, OpenRefine will return the first match.